# How to pass a cookie to an InAppBrowser after logging in to an Apache Cordova App

Tags: cordova, authentication, cookies, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I need to create a login page in a Cordova app, and once the user authenticates successfully, I need to open my mobile-friendly website through the InAppBrowser plugin and pass the retrieved cookie into it so that requests that require authentication do not return an exception.

Is that even possible? If so, an example would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You may try to execute a script on the InAppBrowser, this script would set the cookies manually.
Or simply use a system of preauth, using a request before the opening of the browser (that would get an authentification token).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you elaborate on the pre-auth system please?

Comment: Whats the system used by the cordova app to log in? There can be a preauth token inside the answer, that you could also use in your website (that will be opened by the InAppBrowser), you can try to redirect your user to an https url that includes that preauth token (token usually expires and are GUIDs), and it would log automatically. It really depends on your current login configuration. It can be more complicated if you have no way to obtain that kind of token, because you could have to generate it manually from your website, and your app will have to communicate with thewebsite for auth.

Comment: @Kassem i am having the same issue in ios 10. Were you able to work it out in IOS

Comment: I am also facing similar issues, how can i pass JSESSION ID cookies via inApp browser. please help us.